# How to lookup on a multilevel column in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I am attempting to lookup column E for each 'Payable #', however column E is multilevel with the first selection being empty. Some selection in column E have two items and I would like to extract them both.

I have attempted to "flatten" column E into separate columns but my vlookup keeps failing.

Any advice is appreciated.

[image]

The desired output will look like this if the column is "flattened"

[image]

Comment: please show a mock up of the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to resolve it with `INDEX()` and `MATCH()` functions with are better than the easier `VLOOKUP()`.

The challenge is to detect if you have one or two empty row underneath but with an `IF()` you should be able to make it work:

[image]

Function for first column would be:

```
=+IF(INDEX($B$3:$B$6,MATCH(F5,$B$3:$B$6,1)+1)="",INDEX($C$3:$C$6,MATCH(F5,$B$3:$B$6,1)+1),"")
```

For second column:

```
=+IF(INDEX($B$3:$B$6,MATCH(F5,$B$3:$B$6,1)+2)="",INDEX($C$3:$C$6,MATCH(F5,$B$3:$B$6,1)+2),"")
```